# Twilio on Rails help: not receiving "Digits" parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twilio

I am new to Rails and Twilio, and am trying to run the Twilio Appointment Reminder sample code.  I am able to place the call, but am unable to get any feedback from Twilio about the number keys pressed by the caller.

After the call is made, the reminder TwiML is run: here the Gather command should prompt Twilio to record a single digit input from the caller:

```
xml.instruct!
xml.Response do
    xml.Gather(:action => @post_to, :numDigits => 1) do
        xml.Say "Hello this is a call"
    xml.Say "Please press 1 to repeat this menu. Press 2 for directions. Or press 3 if you are done."
    end
end
```

After a digit is pushed, the Twilio should POST to my directions command in the controller :

```
def directions
  if params['Digits'] == '3'
    redirect_to :action => 'goodbye'
    return
  end

  if !params['Digits'] or params['Digits'] != '2'
    redirect_to :action => 'reminder'
    return
  end

  @redirect_to = BASE_URL + '/reminder'
  render :action => "directions.xml.builder", :layout => false 
end
```

However, every time i call myself and enter a number, the call keeps looping back to the original message.  I then checked my logs and apparently there is no 'Digits' parameter being sent from Twilio.

Anyone encounter this problem?

Comment: Hi Dave. Check to make sure there's not a redirect being returned on the POST request. Test out your URL with sample data using curl or hurl.it to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually what's happening in a case like this is that the URL being posted to immediately issues a redirect because of something like URL rewriting or HTTPS redirection or the like. Twilio follows the redirect and on the subsequent GET request sends along the [standard set of parameters](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request#synchronous-request-parameters) which doesn't include the Digits parameter that is only sent on the initial POST to the `<Gather>` action URL.

Comment: Yes I realized that I was posting to the heroku.com which was redirecting me to herokuapp.com.  Thanks for the help!